# Dynamic Page In DNN 6.0

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I have created a dynamic page in DNN. So I want to know that from where can I find this page in code side when I close my running application.
For example I have created a module which I can find under DesktopModule.

Comment: do you want find a page that you add in a folder for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNN does not create a file on the disk for each page if that is what you are looking for.  All the data for a page is in the database in the Tabs and related tables.